# Omitted Content After Post-Publish Insertion

Tags: custom-post-types, wp-insert-post

I have a string that contains $thehtml but whenever I insert it manually into a custom post it appears that wordpress alters/strips down the html.... I've already tested/outputted $thehtml string in a separate file and its fine.. but wordpress seems to edit/strip the html I insert....

I am inserting via....

```
$post_information = array(
'post_content' => $thehtml,
);
wp_insert_post( $post_information );
```

Example of $thehtml

```
<DIV style="TEXT-ALIGN: center"><FONT style="FONT-FAMILY: Times New Roman" size=2>INFORMATION REQUIRED IN PROXY STATEMENT </FONT></DIV>
```

**After Insertion**.... When I look at HTML in wordpress:

```
<DIV><FONT size="2">INFORMATION REQUIRED IN PROXY STATEMENT </FONT></DIV>
```

Comment: Which function are you using to insert post manually?

Comment: wp_insert_post( $post_information );

Comment: Can you be more specific what html code being stripped? anyway, you may want to check out wp-includes/kses.php which will filter the html code in post content

Comment: @Jesse I have re-edited the main post with example of the HTML code I am inserting and the outcome..... after inserting into wordpress.....

Comment: @John make FONT-FAMILY and TEXT-ALIGN lowercase

Comment: Thanks Jesse for this suggestion, I guess I need to do some string manipulations to get it to change to lowercase....

I also fixed the output example on the top of the page, now you can see it much better in action. Any other suggestions would be welcomed.

Comment: @John so you've made them lowercase and the result is still stripped?

Comment: I tested it today Jesse, and your solution works! The only problem will be turning all of the styling lower case... lots of different cases to go though :(

Comment: @Jesse How do I select your choice as the solution? It won't let me....

Comment: @John don't bother. what it matters is it works for you. haha